# Blank screen after pressing "checkout"

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.0.1

I have just setup Magento DE (from what I understood it is basically the same as standard Magento but comes with some useful extensions for german market) 1.9.0.1 and everything works fine until I get to press the checkout button. The only thing displayed is a blank window, no source code is loaded. Console output shows
GET http://*domain*/index.php/checkout/onepage/ 500 (Internal Server Error) 

What I've tried so far:
Logging in or checking out as a guest
Using webserver rewrites or not (thought I'd give it a try)
Replacing my template with a stock one
Replacing files of the core code that made sense with the original one (haven't changed them ofcourse)
Disabling onepage checkout (only leads to "Checkout" buttons disappearing from basket)
Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is the `mcrypt` php extension enabled on your server?

Comment: I looked it up and it appears to be missing which is strange, because I have another Magento Setup running on the same machine, just not Magento DE. I will try installing mcrypt and try again then. Thanks

Comment: Check web server and PHP logs while you're at it.

Comment: mcrypt is now installed and enabled, everything is restarted.
I checked the logfiles of PHP and apache and could not find anything related. Problem still appears. Any other suggestions? Thank you so far

Comment: edit `index.php` found on root directory and uncomment the code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and refresh the onepage checkout. hope you will get a precise error.

Comment: Well, this definitely helped a lot. It says     
Fatal error: Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in *path*/app/code/community/Netresearch/PaymentFee/Helper/Data.php on line 118
     
which - if I as someone just about to start Magento understand it correctly - does refer to an extension that is delivered with Magento DE. I will look this file up and look for the error. If I cannot find it I will try to disable the extension. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: shall i post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the habits at stackexchange but feel free to do so. Sadly I cannot vote you up since I need 15 rep points for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem but I am not sure why it was solved:

After getting the errorlog which showed "Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in *path*/app/code/community/Netresearch/PaymentFee/Helper/Data.php on line 118" I looked up the file and was not able to find anything wrong with it (although I was not able to find said setName() function).
I then googled the module and found the [module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-payment-fee.html) had some problems with the onepage checkout.
I thought before uninstalling the module I'd try disabling things that it may correspond to and started with payment options. When I disabled BillSafe which has nothing to do with said module AFAIK it worked. I don't need this payment method so that's fine with me and I don't understand how this solved the problem but it did.
I would appreciate anyone finding a reason how this solved the problem and why the error message led me to another extension.
Thank you again for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with a different way, using also Magento 1.9.0.1 DE Version.

There is payment services -> Payment Fee and as for BillSAFE which is activated by default there is a calculation for a fee, i just disabled payment fee and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the feature of a paymentfee, you just have to add an article with sku "paymentfee" and give it a price.

The needed sku can be changed in the settings for billsafe:
[image]